# Getting fancy with Android menu button layouts

Tags: android, button

I am making an Android game and I would like to have a nice menu.  I have only every used the combination of `<LinearLayout>` and `<ImageView>` for placing my buttons, which sets them up in a straight line.  Here are my buttons:

[image]

[image]

I want to place them as seen below.  Is it possible to place a button like that and still make it click-able?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [OnTouchListern](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29) which can be set to any kind of View.

Comment: I think I can probably get a listener working, but doing the rotation it what has me stumped right now. I could just pre-rotate my image, but I would really like to do it in the layout.

Comment: I don't think you can do the rotation in the layout file, I think you have to do it via code.